# How to use the function `Covariance` to calculate covariance correctly?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

**Note:** The following questions are from the 23th question of the [2005 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://max.book118.com/html/2018/1213/8122100042001137.shtm) (first set):

Suppose $X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots, X_{n}(n>2)$ is a simple random sample from population $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$, and $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean ($\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}$),  $Y_{i}=X_{i}-\bar{X}$, $i=1,2, \cdots, n $.

Now we need to solve the following problems:

(1) The variance $D Y_{i}$ of $Y_{i}$,$i=1,2, \cdots, n $.

(2) the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}\left(Y_{1}, Y_{n}\right)$  of $Y_{1}$  and  $Y_{n}$.

I use `n = 10` as a special case to solve this problem:

```
Y1 = TransformedDistribution[x[1] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 10}]/10, 
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, 10}]]
Variance[Y1]
Y10 = TransformedDistribution[x[10] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 10}]/10, 
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, 10}]]
Variance[Y10]
Covariance[Y1, Y10]
Correlation[Y1, Y10]
```

But the above code can't get the covariance of `Y1` and `Y10` correctly (the reference answer is $-\frac{1}{10}$). How can I use the function `Covariance` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use notation that separates random variables from their distributions.  The following code should get you the desired variances and covariances:

```
n = 10; 
distY1Yn = TransformedDistribution[{x[1] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n, x[n] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n}, 
  Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]];
Covariance[distY1Yn]
(* {{9/10, -(1/10)}, {-(1/10), 9/10}} *)
Correlation[distY1Yn]
(* {{1, -(1/9)}, {-(1/9), 1}} *)

distY1 = TransformedDistribution[x[1] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n, 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]];
Variance[distY1]
(* 9/10 *)

distYn = TransformedDistribution[x[n] - Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n, 
   Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]];
Variance[distYn]
(* 9/10 *)
```